# Neo4j with distinct query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following query in neo4j

```
MATCH (chatitems1)-[:PartOf]->(teamsChat)-[:OwnedBy]-()
WITH distinct teamsChat as teams order by teams.id limit 10,chatitems1
return teams
```

I want to select the first 10 different teams.id ordered and the id of chatitems1.

I get the error

```
Invalid input ',': expected 0..9, '.', 'e', 'E', an identifier character, whitespace, node labels, '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR, WHERE, LOAD CSV, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, RETURN, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 2, column 60 (offset: 115))
"WITH distinct teamsChat as teams order by teams.id limit 10,chatitems1"
```

Final query is

```
MATCH (user)-[:CreatesChat]-(chatitems)
WITH user ORDER BY user.id DESC LIMIT 10
MATCH (chatitems1)-[:PartOf]->(teamsChat)-[:OwnedBy]-()
WITH distinct teamsChat as teams,user,chatitems1
with user,chatitems1, teams as teams1 order by teams.id limit 10
with distinct user as users1, chatitems1, teams1
return chatitems1,teams1
```

I want to keep teamsChat.id  for use later,

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

1. you should use labels
2. the first part of your query expands paths, so you get duplicate users
3. use directions
4. you have a lot of duplicate with's which look like you're unsure what you'd use them for?
5. I don't think you need the last DISTINCT

try this:

```
MATCH (user:User)
WHERE SIZE( (user)-[:CreatesChat]->() ) > 0
WITH user ORDER BY user.id DESC LIMIT 10
MATCH (user)-[:CreatesChat]->(chatitems)-[:PartOf]->(teams)
WHERE (teamsChat)-[:OwnedBy]-()
RETURN teams,user, chatitems 
ORDER BY teams.id limit 10
```

In a real world query you probably want to return certain attributes of your nodes.

Comment: can you please elaborate why you did what you did? when do you decide to use WHERE in opposed to a longer query with filtering by relations?